# How to plot the 5 most repeated items in a list?

Tags: python

I want  to plot just the 5 most repeated item in my list:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter

result= [162, 152, 47, 116, 34, 199, 69, 34, 51, 109, 89, 244, 30, 51, 151, 21, 88, 75, 75, 25, 221, 30, 75, 180, 21, 75, 41, 21, 30, 21, 183, 41, 117, 78, 88,162]
print(Counter(result))
counts= Counter(result)
common = counts.most_common()
labels = [item[0] for item in common]
number = [item[1] for item in common]
nbars = len(common)

plt.bar(np.arange(nbars), number, tick_label=labels)
plt.show()
```

My code plots all item, however I want just the 5  most repeated.

Comment: I see your code but you haven't indicated what's wrong with it.  What do you think is wrong with it?  How does your output differ from your desired output?

Comment: Here's the [`Counter.most_common`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) documentation. You can ask `.most_common` for only the top 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`most_common()` can take an optional number `n` for the most common `n`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> result= [162, 152, 47, 116, 34, 199, 69, 34, 51, 109, 89, 244, 30, 51, 151, 21, 88, 75, 75, 25, 221, 30, 75, 180, 21, 75, 41, 21, 30, 21, 183, 41, 117, 78, 88,162]
>>> common = Counter(result).most_common(5)
>>> print(common)
[(21, 4), (75, 4), (30, 3), (162, 2), (41, 2)]
```